# How to get rid of all the if statements in here

Tags: python

I have the following class in Python.

```
class FEOProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = Extractor()
        self.result = {'Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization' : 
                       'Not Applied', 
                       'HTML5 Advanced Cache' : 'Not Applied',
                       'Cookieless Resource Domain' : 'Not Applied',
                       'Minificatiopn of JS' : 'Not Applied',
                       'File Versioning' : 'Not Applied',
                       'Small Image Embedding' : 'Not Applied',
                       'Responsive Image Loading' : 'Not Applied',
                       'Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading' : 'Not Applied',
                       'JS Pre-Execution' : 'Not Applied'
                       }

    def check_js_inlining(self, result):
        if 'EMBED_JAVASCRIPT' in result:
            return result['EMBED_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0

    def check_html5_advanced_cache(self, result):
        if 'JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE' in result:
            return result['JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE'] > 0 and result['CSS_HTML5_CACHE'] > 0

    def check_cookieless_resource_domain(self,result):
        if 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT' in result and 'RENAME_CSS' in result:
            return result['RENAME_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0 and result['RENAME_CSS'] > 0

    def check_js_minifaction(self, result):
        if 'MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT' in result:
            return result['MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0

    def check_file_versioning(self, result):
        if 'RENAME_JAVASCRIPT' in result and 'RENAME_IMAGE' in result and 'RENAME_CSS' in result:
            return result['RENAME_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0 and result['RENAME_IMAGE'] > 0 and result['RENAME_CSS'] > 0

    def check_small_image_embedding(self, result):
        if 'EMBED_IMAGE' in result:
            return result['EMBED_IMAGE'] > 0

    def check_responsive_image_loading(self, result):
        if 'RESPONSIVE_IMAGES' in result:
            return result['RESPONSIVE_IMAGES'] > 0

    def check_async_js_and_css_loading(self, result):
        if 'ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT' in result:
            return result['ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0

    def check_js_pre_execution(self, result):
        if 'PRE_EXECUTE_JAVASCRIPT' in result:
            return result['PRE_EXECUTE_JAVASCRIPT'] > 0



    def process_feo_debug_output(self, analysis_id, url):
        feed = self.parser.start_parser(analysis_id, url, True)
        result = self.get_feo_tags(feed)
        if self.check_js_inlining(result):
            self.result['Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_html5_advanced_cache(result):
            self.result['HTML5 Advanced Cache'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_cookieless_resource_domain(result):
            self.result['Cookieless Resource Domain'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_js_minifaction(result):
            self.result['Minificatiopn of JS'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_file_versioning(result):
            self.result['File Versioning'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_small_image_embedding(result):
            self.result['Small Image Embedding'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_responsive_image_loading(result):
            self.result['Responsive Image Loading'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_async_js_and_css_loading(result):
            self.result['Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading'] = 'Applied'
        if self.check_js_pre_execution(result):
            self.result['JS Pre-Execution'] = 'Applied'
        return self.result



    def get_feo_tags(self, feed):
        result = {}
        tag_list = re.findall(r'(?:TextTransApplied):\s*((?:(?:[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+)?\(\d+\)\s*(?:,\s*|;))*)', str(feed))
        for tag in tag_list:
            for element in tag.split(","):
                index = element.index('(')
                if element[:index].strip():
                    result[element[:index].strip()] = (element.split("(")[1].rstrip(");"))
        return result



processor = FEOProcessor()
print processor.process_feo_debug_output('123d','http://in.strawberrynet.com/main.aspx')
```

Initally the result is all not applied dict. Now based on the result that I get I update the dict. Can this be written in a better way .

Comment: You could create a dictionnary with you functions name as key and your `result` dict keys as values and then iterate through it.

Comment: Can you just give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of all `if`s, you can use a struct, defining your checks:

```
class FEOProcessor(object):
    CHECKS = [
        ('Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization', ('EMBED_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_inlining'),
        ('HTML5 Advanced Cache', ('JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE', 'CSS_HTML5_CACHE'), 'check_html5_advanced_cache'),
        ('Cookieless Resource Domain', ('RENAME_JAVASCRIPT', 'RENAME_CSS'), 'check_cookieless_resource_domain'),
        ('Minificatiopn of JS', ('MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_minifaction'),
        ('File Versioning', ('RENAME_JAVASCRIPT', 'RENAME_IMAGE', 'RENAME_CSS'), 'check_file_versioning'),
        ('Small Image Embedding', ('EMBED_IMAGE',), 'check_small_image_embedding'),
        ('Responsive Image Loading', ('RESPONSIVE_IMAGES',), 'check_responsive_image_loading'),
        ('Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading', ('ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_async_js_and_css_loading'),
        ('JS Pre-Execution', ('PRE_EXECUTE_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_js_pre_execution'),
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = Extractor()
        self.result = dict((k, 'Not Applied') for k,_,_ in self.CHECKS)

    for _, keys, name in CHECKS:
        locals()[name] = lambda self, result, _keys=keys: all(result.get(k, 0)>0 for k in _keys)

    def process_feo_debug_output(self, analysis_id, url):
        feed = self.parser.start_parser(analysis_id, url, True)
        result = self.get_feo_tags(feed)
        for name, _, func in self.CHECKS:
            self.result[name] = ('Not Applied','Applied')[getattr(self,func)(result)]
        return self.result

    def get_feo_tags(self, feed):
        result = {}
        tag_list = re.findall(r'(?:TextTransApplied):\s*((?:(?:[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+)?\(\d+\)\s*(?:,\s*|;))*)', str(feed))
        for tag in tag_list:
            for element in tag.split(","):
                index = element.index('(')
                if element[:index].strip():
                    result[element[:index].strip()] = (element.split("(")[1].rstrip(");"))
        return result
```

Comment: Gives an error as `File "FEO_processor.py", line 14, in FEOProcessor
    ('Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading', ('ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT',), 'check_async_js_and_css_loading'),
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: Figured out. Missing comma. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here is what you could do to avoid having that many `if` statement, create a dictionary with all your functions name as `key` and all you `self.result` dict `keys` as `values`:

```
class FEOProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = Extractor()
        self.result = {
            'Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization': 'Not Applied', 
            'HTML5 Advanced Cache' : 'Not Applied',
            'Cookieless Resource Domain' : 'Not Applied',
            'Minificatiopn of JS' : 'Not Applied',
            'File Versioning' : 'Not Applied',
            'Small Image Embedding' : 'Not Applied',
            'Responsive Image Loading' : 'Not Applied',
            'Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading' : 'Not Applied',
            'JS Pre-Execution' : 'Not Applied'
        }


    # All your functions...

    def process_feo_debug_output(self, analysis_id, url):
        feed = self.parser.start_parser(analysis_id, url, True)
        result = self.get_feo_tags(feed)
        func_dict = { 
            self.check_js_inlining: 'Standard JavaScript Inlining Optimization',
            self.check_html5_advanced_cache: 'HTML5 Advanced Cache',
            self.check_cookieless_resource_domain: 'Cookieless Resource Domain',
            self.check_js_minifaction: 'Minificatiopn of JS',
            self.check_file_versioning: 'File Versioning',
            self.check_small_image_embedding: 'Small Image Embedding',
            self.check_responsive_image_loading: 'Responsive Image Loading',
            self.check_async_js_and_css_loading: 'Asynchronous JS and CSS Loading',
            self.check_js_pre_execution: 'JS Pre-Execution'
        }
        for key, value in func_dict.iteritems():
            if key(result):
                self.result[value] = 'Applied'
```

Comment: It tells me `global name 'check_js_inlining' is not defined` . Should I put that in quotes . I though python interpreter would have the function definition by now

Comment: Try to add the `self` statement infront of each function and tell me if that works